# neo4jrb how to reset transaction timeout of an open transaction

Tags: neo4j, neo4j.rb

Currently using neo4j-community-2.1.7

I understand that the facility has been included in this version.

Have been unable to find any reference to it in the ruby docs.

Would appreciate it very much if I may have some direction on how to reset the timeout using neo4jrb.

Regards
Ross

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the transaction timeout?  Is that a Neo4j thing?  I assume you're using embedded mode since you're using the `neo4j-community` gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unaware of a way to reset the transaction timeout of an open transaction. Maybe someone more familiar with transactions in the Java API can clarify.

If you want to change the transaction timeout length at boot, that's handled in `neo4j-server.properties` as described at http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-configuration.html.

Within Neo4j-core, if using Neo4j-community or Neo4j-enterprise (and therefore Neo4j Embedded) the code suggests that you can specify a config file by giving a third argument to `Neo4j::Session.open`, a hash that contains config options. That method, if given `:embedded_db` as its first arg, will call `Neo4j::Embedded#initialize` and give that hash as an argument. If you do something like this:

```
Neo4j::Session.open(:embedded_db, 'path_to_db', properties_file: 'path_and_filename_to_neo4j-server.properties')
```

It will eventually use that properties file:

```
db_service.loadPropertiesFromFile(properties_file) if properties_file
```

This is not demonstrated in any of the specs, unfortunately, but you can see it in the `initialize` and `start` methods at https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core/blob/230d69371ed6bf39297786155ef4f3b1831dac08/lib/neo4j-embedded/embedded_session.rb.

**RE: COMMENT INFO**

If you're using `:server_db`, you don't need to include the `neo4j-community` gem. It isn't loaded, it isn't compatible with Neo4j in Server mode.

That's the first time I've seen the link you provided, good to know that's there. We don't expose a way to do that in Neo4j.rb and won't because it would require some threading magic that we can't support. If you want to do it manually, the best I can tell you is that you can get a current transaction ID this way:

```
tx = Neo4j::Transaction.new
# do stuff and before your long-running query...
tx.resource_data[:commit].split('/')[-2]
```

That will return the transaction number that you can use in POST as described in their support doc.

If you'd like help troubleshooting your long-running Cypher query, I'm sure people on SO will help.

Comment: I'm not using embedded, as session is started this way: session = Neo4j::Session.open(:server_db). I've read the properties files in .conf directory and see no reference to setting the transaction time out value, so I guess I'm not that surprised to find no reference in the rubydocs or the gem code to resetting a transaction time out either. Am I missing something or is it just missing the the ruby implementation? The question arises because I do have a transaction which occasionally (& apparently) times out & I'm trying to find a way to deal with that other than by rescuing it -- see more ...

Comment: that is, resetting the time out as documented in - http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-reset-transaction-timeout-of-an-open-transaction

Comment: That's interesting. I'll add to my answer, it's too much to leave in a comment.

Comment: Works perfectly. Incidentally, I only require 'neo4j' in the code. The reference to the community edition was for the server version. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Ah, my mistake! We have an actual `neo4j-community` gem that contains Java jar files. I misunderstood.